# DataGrid auto scroll to bottom for newly added item

Tags: c#, wpf

I use an `ObservableCollection` in my `ViewModel` to add a new record in my `DataGrid`, so I don't have an access to this control. I wanted to scroll to the bottom of the `DataGrid` every time **a new item is added**.

Normally I can just hook into `INotifyCollectionChanged` from my View, then scroll to the bottom, something like;

```
public MyView(){
    InitializeComponent();
    CollectionView myCollectionView = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyDataGrid.Items);
    ((INotifyCollectionChanged)myCollectionView).CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(DataGrid_CollectionChanged);
}

private void DataGrid_CollectionChanged(object? sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e){
    if (MyDataGrid.Items.Count > 0){
        if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(MyDataGrid, 0) is Decorator border){
            if (border.Child is ScrollViewer scroll) scroll.ScrollToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

My problem now is that I have a function to `Duplicate` and `Delete` an item, this whole thing is being done in my `ViewModel`. With the approach above, the DataGrid will always scroll to the bottom even if I deleted or duplicate an item in any position which I don't want to happen. Scrolling to the bottom should only be working for the newly added items.

What should be the approach for this?

Comment: The NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs should have informations about what have been modified (like Action).
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedeventargs.action?view=net-6.0#system-collections-specialized-notifycollectionchangedeventargs-action

Comment: That could work, I can just add a condition: `if (DataGridDisbursement.Items.Count > 0 && e.Action.Equals(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)){  .... }`. However, when adding items, I used `observablecollection.add()`, and when duplicating the item I used `observablecollection.insert(indexPosition, item)` which both will result of `add` action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options, first is to compare the difference between the old and new items. Then simply get that item and using `DataGrid.ScrollIntoView(item)` to scroll into that specific position.

```
private void DataGrid_CollectionChanged(object? sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e){
    if (YourDataGrid.Items.Count > 0 && e.Action.Equals(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)){ //Do this only when new item is added.
        if (sender is not CollectionView oldItems) return;
            foreach (var oldItem in oldItems) {
                foreach (var newItem in (e.NewItems)??new ObservableCollection<TransactionItem>()){
                    if (!newItem.Equals(oldItem)){
                        YourDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(newItem); //Scroll into this specific item.   
                        return; //No need to do further checking
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, the same behavior with the answer of [@Paolo Iommarini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/848520/paolo-iommarini) will be expected when you duplicate the last item. Making his approach much better compared to this in terms of performance.

The second option and much better is by using `Events`. You simply need to define it into your `ViewModel`, then invoke the event every time a new item is added passing the argument as the newly added item. From your `View`, subscribe into that event and use `DataGrid.ScrollIntoView(item)` to scroll.

Here is a more detailed example, in your `ViewModel`.

```
public class ViewModel{
 
  //define the event in the ViewModel.
  public delegate void MyEventAction(YourObjectModelItem item);
  public event MyEventAction? MyEvent;
  
  private void AddNewItem(){ //Assuming this function is being called to add the item into your ObservableCollection.
     var new_item = .... //(1) create your item.
     YourObServableCollection.Add(new_item); //(2) add the item into your collection.
     MyEvent?.Invoke(new_item); //(3) invoke the event and pass the new item as the argument.
  }
  
}
```

Then in your `View`.

```
public YourView(){
    InitializeComponent();
    ...
    this.Loaded += (s, a) => { //You should subscribe only when the view is loaded, otherwise you might get a null issue with your DataContext. You may also use DataContextChanged if you want.
        var vm = (ViewModel)DataContext; //(1) Get the ViewModel from your DataContext.
        vm.MyEvent += (item) =>{  //(2) Subscribe to the event from the ViewModel.
            YourDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(item); //(3) Scroll to that item.
        };
    };
}
```

With this approach, you don't have to make any comparison. You just need to know which item you will be scrolling.

Comment: Interesting, I was actually thinking of this approach. An event that can be raised from the ViewModel in order to notify the View of the newly added item. This is much faster than the comparison or checking approach. Can't vote for your answer but thanks for `ScrollIntoView`, line of code has been reduce.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to check if NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs.NewStartingIndex is at the end of your collection. You should scroll to the end only if the change has happened at the end.

```
private void DataGrid_CollectionChanged(object? sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e){
    if (MyDataGrid.Items.Count > 0 && e.NewStartingIndex == MyDataGrid.Items.Count - 1){
        if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(MyDataGrid, 0) is Decorator border){
            if (border.Child is ScrollViewer scroll) scroll.ScrollToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the passed `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` to identify whether a `Duplicate` or `Delete` has occurred.

`Delete` is easy, simply:

```cs
if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
{
    // An item has been removed from your collection. Do not scroll.
}
```

`Duplicate` depends on your definition of what a "duplicate" or "copy" is exactly, but most likely you can use a quick Linq check like:

```cs
if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
{
    // An item has been added, let's see if it's a duplicate.
    CollectionView changedCollection = (CollectionView)sender;
    foreach (myRecordType record in e.NewItems)
    {
        if (changedCollection.Contains(record))
        {
             // This was likely a duplicate added
        }
    }
}
```

It's worth noting that `EventArgs` of any type are really there for this very purpose. They'll generally provide you with more information regarding the event for exactly this kind of logical handling.

Comment: This could work, but I'm actually trying to avoid any comparison due to performance issues. For example, this can cause a little time of blocking of UI for multiple items, say 200 items.

Comment: Perhaps, there is a way to raise an event from my `ViewModel` then the `View` can listen to it? FYI I'm just learning C# WPF for almost four months now so I am not really sure if this idea does allow or exists in MVVM.

Comment: Respectfully, so long as you're not running this on a potato, 200 entries of record type data (a handful of value type properties), you shouldn't worry about performance issues on a simple comparison. Of course if you do need to avoid this kind of checking, you would need ensure that your `Duplicate` method you've written on `CollectionView` never raises the `NotifyCollectionChangedEvent` in the first place.

Comment: The blocking of UI is noticeable with 200 entries (even with 100 entries) when comparing duplicate items, I tried your approach. I can use `async/await` but that makes the same delayed, the only difference is that it doesn't block the UI. I can't think of any way to duplicate the item without raising the `NotifyCollectionChangedEvent` since I used `obscollection.insert(indexPosition, item)`.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that the approach above will likely fail when items have a different id unless I made an exception to the id which I think will be overkill. Anyway, thank you for your solution, very much appreciated.

Comment: It's hard for me to say without known more about your record type, I'm very surprised you see a UI blocking on a 100 entities. Your comment regarding "ID" also suggests that "duplicates" are not entirely equal to one another in the value sense, so yes, you'd need a lower level solution. You'll see in the `ObservableCollection<T>` source that `InsertItem` (https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/observablecollection.cs) raises the event as an Add action.

Comment: A hack solution would be that the UI end of your duplicate process (a button click?), removed the event handler from the grid and then adds it back after you're done, but... ewww. Otherwise you'll need to write your own collection class implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged` and take control of when and how the event is raised.

Comment: Would it be enough to check for NewStartingIndex? If NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs.NewStartingIndex is equal to the count - 1 of your collection than you should scroll to end.

Comment: Unless you've duplicated the last item, or removed it ;) but I guessed OP might still like to scroll in that case. The issue simply becomes: "If the change has happened at the end of the collection, scroll there". I think this a solid idea, why not write it up as an answer!?

Comment: Pretty much interesting about `NewStartingIndex`. When the user duplicates the last entry, it also scrolled into it which is not that bad at all.

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood No, thanks. I rather use your approach than do that hacky trick. Anyway, the ID is the identifier of each item. Even a duplicate item needs an identifier, right? The ID is just the incrementing count of each index.